# R data.table problem with grouping by numeric column returns NaN

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

I'm looking for any solution to perform my function for standardization on dataset including numeric datepoint which I'd like to use for grouping. When I run the function it returns me NaN values and when change to character string it works. How to use numeric variable for grouping.

```
#function
standardize <- function(value, weight, stimulant){

  result <-
    weight *
    (
      ifelse(stimulant == T, 1, -1) -
        (
          (value - min(value, na.rm = T))/(max(value, na.rm = T) - min(value, na.rm = T))
        )
    )
}

# data
dt <- data.table(
  group1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
  group2 = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
  rate = c(0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 0.100, 0.55, 0, 0.95)
)

# implement
dt[, standardized_rate := standardize(rate, weight = 0.2, stimulant = TRUE), by = .(group1, group2)]
```

Comment: you have only one value in each group (if grouped by both `group1` and `group2`), then the denominator `max(value, na.rm = T) - min(value, na.rm = T)` would be zero in your function.